# reactJS - show form input when browser goes back

Tags: reactjs

I have form, after submitting user will be taken to another page. If they click browser go back button, they will go back to the form but input data is no longer there.

What the proper way to recover input data in react?

form:

```
export default class Update extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
            }
        };
    }
    updateContact(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // saving data
        // then redirect 
        this.context.router.push('/');
    }
    render(){ 
        return(
            <form id="new-form" onSubmit={this.updateContact.bind(this)}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"  />
                <button type="submit" class="btn" >Update</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}


Update.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just rely on the browser to do it for you because it won't work, especially with dynamically created forms.

What you need is a proper state managing infrastructure. It looks like you use react router. You would have to manage your own state for each page in history then save the data. To make it persist, you can use localStorage, sessionStorage, or even more robust options such as localForage or server side syncing.

Then you would execute a callback on route change that will restore state in components.

There isn't a boilerplate way to do this automatically. You have to implement it for your form.

You can see how [scroll-behavior](https://github.com/taion/scroll-behavior) library does that for persisting scroll offset with history changes.